# How to type a class decorator adding additional methods to a class

Tags: python, types

I have a class decorator that is adding additional methods to a class:

```
def add_method(cls):
  def new_method(self):
    pass
  setattr(cls, 'new_method', new_method)
  return cls

@add_method  
class Klass():
  pass

k = Klass()
k.new_method() # Typechecker complains about lack of new_method
```

Now I understand *why* I get the error. But I can't wrap my head around how to avoid it. How do I tell the typing system that the thing decorated by `add_method` has a `new_method` member (and what it's signature is).

I tried several approaches with Union types and Protocols and what not, but I didn't really get anything to work. The only solution I can come up with is to ditch the decorator and go the inheritance/mixin route with `Klass` inheriting from a `MethodMixin` class or similar, but would prefer a decorator based solution -- or at least wonder if one exists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return your class from the decorator, in other case, you will end up with empty class.
Here is how it should look like:

```
def add_method(cls):
    def new_method(self):
        pass
    setattr(cls, 'new_method', new_method)
    return cls

@add_method  
class Klass():
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you. This indeed is a bug in the code in my question. It wasn't in the original code that I was facing the issue with though. The typechecker will not find `new_method` on `Klass`, even when `cls` gets returned.

Answer (score -1):

Try to define a return type for it to work.

```
def add_method(cls):
  def new_method(self):
    return []
  setattr(cls, 'new_method', new_method)
```

Because the function itself is not defined, Python won't create it in the object.

Comment: This answer confuses me. Not returning a value from new_method should make it return `None` implicitly. And not defining a body for the function should not prevent Python from creating the function. And even then, it would still try to attach a at that point undefined function to the `new_method` attribute on cls. I also want to call out that the code runs and works as expected, it just doesn't typecheck well. I appreciate your attempt at an answer, but I think we are completely off track here.